# How do I display ASCII ART in php properly?

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to display some ASCII ART in my profile's bio.
When I save and fetch the data to show, the ASCII ART displays in inline and not keeping the same letter distribution per line which is in the art. How can I rectify this? Please help...! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the PRE html tag around your ascii art. That makes your newlines remain as newlines when rendered on the page. You may also want to use css to specify a font that is a fixed width font.

```
<pre style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace"><?php echo $asciiart; ?></pre>
```

And obviously inside the variable `$asciiart` the `\n` would be used to represent newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Php doesn't parse new lines unless you ask for it. you need to add a `\n` at the end of each line of art

```
$art = '  /\_/\ \n
        =( °w° )= \n
          )   (  // \n
         (__ __)// \n';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this too:

```
<?php

$name = ' ASCII ART with the first letter of my name:

******** 
*******
**
*****
**
**
**';


echo "<pre>";
echo $name;
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

And you will get this:

ASCII ART:

```
******** 
*******
**
*****
**
**
**
```

EDIT: I just realized that @developerwjk did the same, but maybe it's more clear this way so I will leave my answer just in case it's useful.